# How can I fix errors on this page?

Tags: python, django, webserver

These errors occur when you enter the admin page. I want to fix this. Help me.
problem[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMb1O.png)

### Source code

urls.py-fistsite

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from polls import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('/polls', include('polls.urls')),
    path('/admin', include('polls.urls'))
]
```

urls.py-polls

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/result/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote')
]
```

Comment: This problem is not solved yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your urls.py to this and it should work.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls), # add this
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

For some reason you changed the site admin's url to `include('polls.urls')` which is incorrect. Change it back to `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)` and django will pick it up. And on the side note, You don't have to add `/` django has a middleware that does it automatically.